# Intervalo de confiança

Tags: r, glm, glmer, lme4

Eu gostaria de gerar os valores do intervalo de confiança para algumas variáveis explicativas da variável resposta HUNTED. Os dados estão distribuídos em 3 PERÍODOS de tempo distintos. No entanto, quando eu uso o código: 
library (MASS) 
confint (allspecies4) 
eu só recebo mensagens de erro (veja abaixo). Alguém saberia como melhorar meu script para que eu possa acessar o intervalo de confiança? 
Obs.: Meu conjunto de dados é muito grande, então só coloquei aqui uma parte dele.

```js
allspecies4<-read.csv(file= "dadosGLMM.csv", header= TRUE, sep= ";" )
attach(allspecies4)
library(lme4)
allspecies4<- glmer(HUNTED~ eco+TrophicLevel+age+ log(body_mass)+
                      habitat+ABUND + PERIOD + tabu +(1|Specie),
                    data=dadosGLMM, family=binomial)

library(MASS)
confint(allspecies4)
```

```css
library(MASS)
> confint(allspecies4)
Computing profile confidence intervals ...
Error in zeta(shiftpar, start = opt[seqpar1][-w]) : 
  profiling detected new, lower deviance
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
2: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
3: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
4: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
5: In (function (fn, par, lower = rep.int(-Inf, n), upper = rep.int(Inf,  :
  failure to converge in 10000 evaluations
6: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
7: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
8: In nextpar(mat, cc, i, delta, lowcut, upcut) :
  unexpected decrease in profile: using minstep
9: In FUN(X[[i]], ...) : non-monotonic profile for (Intercept)
```

```html
Specie body_mass TrophicLevel age eco habitat PERIOD HUNTED ABUND tabu
  Cerc_mit      3.70            2  57   2       F DURING      0     2    1
  Cerc_mit      3.70            2  57   2       F  AFTER      0     3    1
  Cerc_mit      3.70            2  57   2       F BEFORE      0     4    1
  Cerc_mit      3.70            2  67   2       F DURING      1     2    1
  Cerc_mit      3.70            2  67   2       F  AFTER      0     2    1
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  53   2       S DURING      0     3    0
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  74   2       S DURING      0     3    0
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  30   2       S DURING      0     4    0
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  63   2       S DURING      0     4    0
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  54   2       S DURING      0     3    0
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  30   2       S DURING      0     4    0
 Chlor_cyn      3.70            2  30   2       S DURING      0     3    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  24   3       F DURING      0     3    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  24   3       F BEFORE      0     4    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  33   3       F  AFTER      1     4    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  33   3       F BEFORE      0     4    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  33   3       F DURING      0     4    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  43   3       F BEFORE      0     4    0
 Phil_mont      3.69            2  43   3       F DURING      0     4    0
```

Comment: 1) Este subconjunto dos dados não chega, dá-me erro *"fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 3 columns / coefficients"* e *"Warning messages: 2: Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined"*. 2) No seu código faz `allspecies4<-read.csv(...)` mas depois `allspecies4<- glmer(..., data=dadosGLMM)` quando o nome dos dados **não é o nome do ficheiro**, é `allspecies4`. E deve usar outro nome para o modelo, nunca o nome da data.frame. 3) Nunca use `attach`, não faz nada de útil e pode ser ser perigoso. Apague essa linha depressa e não pense mais nisso.